# Stuck in xmonad with mod key not working - how to recover?

Tags: xmonad

I am trying NixOS, and have a problem with fairly basic configuration. Basically, I experimented with xkboptions in configuration.nix, and lost the xmonad mod key when I tried to switch alt and win keys.

Now, every time I boot, I am offered none+xmonad session, as I configured that intentionally. But, when I log in, I am stuck. Since mod is not working, I cannot quit xmonad to console, I cannot open terminal to try to recover...

I would know how to recover if I had a way to reach terminal, but I do not know how to do that. Is there some way to avoid entering xmonad on login (which is the default) and to just drop into the terminal without X?

Answer (score 0):

You probably solved that already, but...

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>  will take you to a command line with no X booted screen on most Linux distributions.